# Rails - Archive tables into another database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

We have some tables that have huge number of records and which are not used often(e.g. `user_activities`) and we want to have ability to archive(I mean move) records from target table into archive table in separate database.

My question is: are there known solutions for that?

**Additional explanation:**
I'd like to have some kind of a rake task that would trigger archiving process. The process would go through tables marked as 'archived' (or whatever) and move outdated records to archive table in separate database.

**Example**: `user_activities` has 30 000 records. I mark the table as archived and set cutoff by id  - last 2000 records. I expect the following results:

1. `user_activities` contains latest 2000 records only
2. 28 000 outdated records have been moved to `archived_user_activities` table in `my_super_cool_named_database`

**PS** we use `mysql2` adapter (if it helps)

Thank you!

Comment: Gut feeling tells me you'll lose less time writing this yourself then figuring out a gem/framework to do it

Comment: @Sancho.RubyROID: did you find find a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is the dump command and restore command I have shown below that work with the entire database.

copy the database: 
mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]

Use this method to rebuild a database from scratch:
$ mysql -u [username] -p [password] [database_to_restore] < [backupfile]

Use this method to import into an existing database (i.e. to restore a database that already exists):
$ mysqlimport [options] database textfile1

To restore your previously created custback.sql dump back to your 'Customers' MySQL database, you'd use:
$ mysqlimport -u sadmin -p pass21 Customers custback.sql

Although if you only want a specific part of the db you can do something like this...

```
 CREATE TABLE db2.table LIKE db1.table;
 INSERT INTO db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table;
```